# How to convert a node gd image to a stream that I can pipe?

Tags: node.js, image, stream, gd, fs

I'm using node-gd to process images, but I'd like to do a few things before saving them to the disk. Right now I save the file with the .savePng() and .saveJpeg() functions.

I'd like to convert it to a stream which can be piped to an FS stream.

I tried the module streamifier because it sounds like it would do what I need, but when running the code below, the exported image is unreadable (though the same size as exporting via node-gd).

Here is what I attempted to do:

```
var gd = require("node-gd");
var fs = require("fs");
const streamifier = require('streamifier');

var inputImage = gd.createFromPng('input.png');

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.png');

var pngstream = inputImage.pngPtr();

streamifier.createReadStream(pngstream).pipe(writeStream);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The png pointer needs to first be converted to a buffer like so

```
var pngstream = Buffer.from(inputImage.pngPtr(), 'binary');
```

Comment: `var pngstream = inputImage.pngPtr(-1, true);` in which `-1` is default compression and `true` means return a Buffer.